# How do I pass variables as arguments to a delta lake table_changes_by_path query?

Tags: scope, databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I am generating a target table from a source, refreshing it periodically. I am tracking the target table's version history of the source so that I can update only for those versions of the source data that are new relative to the last update.

To do this, I would like to take the current and last-update version number of the source table and pass these as arguments to a `table_change_by_path` function call. However, it throws an error when I pass variables to the call: `[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITHOUT_SUGGESTION] A column, variable, or function parameter with name` current `cannot be resolved. ; line 2 pos 5`

If I put integers directly in the call to `table_changes_by_path()` all goes well and I can SELECT from the temporary view. If I define variables, I cannot do this. In the initial creation of the view it looks like everything is OK regardless of the method I use (databricks does not throw an error for this, and if I reverse-order the integer variables for the start and end versions it does correctly note that this is not possible).

Below is a variant where I define the variables where I would expect it to return the whole view but instead I receive the unresolved column error above.

```
DECLARE OR REPLACE VARIABLE current INT;
SET VARIABLE current = 30;

DECLARE OR REPLACE VARIABLE previous INT;
SET VARIABLE previous = 11;

CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW tempview AS 
SELECT * FROM table_changes_by_path(table,
  previous,
  current);

SELECT * FROM tempview;
```